# Simplest cloud storage service API

Tags: java, web-applications, google-drive-api, dropbox, onedrive

I need to create a Java web app that uses the API of at least two different cloud storage providers (Google Drive, Dropbox, SkyDrive, Mega, ...).
I'm wondering if there's someone with experience using these APIs who can tell which are the easiest to use and which are the most difficult...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temboo supports a number of cloud storage APIs, and can generate the Java source code you need to access them.

See here: https://live.temboo.com/library/keyword/storage/

By normalizing API access, Temboo makes talking to one API as easy as talking to the next, so it sounds like something that you'll find useful for this project.

Full disclosure: I work at Temboo.

Comment: Thanks, it looks really good, but what about licensing issues? Can I use Temboo freely in my projects?

Comment: Yes you can - there are no licensing issues. We simply wrap access to publicly available APIs, making them appear consistent and easier to use. We adhere to API terms of service.

Comment: Alright, so I'm only subject to APIs terms, right?I'll take a deep look, but it seems like you did a good work... you can't tell me about the compatibility with Google App Engine, can you?

Comment: Exactly, you're subject to the API terms. Also, our free tier limits you to a certain number of calls (10,000) and data transfer (512MB) per month. 

As regards Google App Engine, we have used Temboo in that context before, but unfortunately it's not something we have documented.

Answer (score 9):

[Kloudless](https://developers.kloudless.com/) provides a common API to several different cloud storage APIs (Dropbox, Box, GDrive, OneDrive, etc.). Kloudless also provides SDKs in popular languages and UI widgets to handle authentication and other user interactions.

You can find more information and sign up here: https://developers.kloudless.com/

Full disclosure: I work at Kloudless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40319448/1356559

Answer (score 5):

The [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/) service is very simple, and I've had great experiences working with it for large files and large numbers of files in the context of web services.  Once you've signed up for the service, you can use the [RESTful API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html) to create buckets and upload objects to them.  The [Java library](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) is the reference library for interfacing with the services, although there are ports to other languages as well (such as [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) for Python).

Answer (score 1):

After a very little research on this subject, I've found out that probably the cloud storage provider with the simplest API is [**MediaFire**](http://www.mediafire.com/), which offers really simple interaction through **RESTful** services. You can see the [**API documentation**](http://developers.mediafire.com/index.php/REST_API). I've not yet started working deeply with this API, but it seems to provided all the basic functionalities.

The API served by **[Box](https://www.box.com/)** seems to be also quite simple. It uses [**OAuth 2.0**](http://oauth.net/2/), which makes it more secure. See [**developers website**](http://developers.box.com/).

The SOAP API from [**4sync**](http://www.4sync.com/) is also really simple. There's no much documentation and the samples in the website seem to be from an older version, but anyway it is very easy to use. See documentation [**here**](http://www.4sync.com/developer/docs/intro/).