# Kloudless: How to Download/upload file

Tags: java, objective-c, kloudless

I am trying Kloudless [interactive docs](https://developers.kloudless.com/interactive-docs/#!/accounts/Account_retrieve), I have created application account and linked it to my google account so it has access to google drive, Now given a simple file `config.txt` located in the root , and given that I supplied the correct `account_id`,

[image]

then remains the file `id` that is the path of the file to be downloaded, I have tried `root/config.txt` and `config.txt` but it returns 404 (not found)

what is needed to make this request work, I will be using both objective-c and java

Answer (score 1):

(Hi! I work at Kloudless)

All files/folders and other objects are represented by Kloudless IDs. Check out the [walkthrough](https://developers.kloudless.com/applications/*/walkthrough) for an example of how to retrieve the contents of the root folder. The documentation for [retrieving folder contents](https://developers.kloudless.com/docs/latest/storage#folders-retrieve-folder-contents) has an example as well, indicating how the Account ID and Folder ID should be used to retrieve the contents of that folder. For the root folder, you may use the special ID `root`:

```
# Assuming the account ID 123:
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]' \
'https://api.kloudless.com/v1/accounts/123/storage/folders/root/contents'
```